# I have two bootcamp partitions but not my original 500GB

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, mojave, external-disk

I have a mid 2014 MacBook Pro running Mojave. I recently tried to dual boot windows on my MacBook but in the process corrupted my original Macintosh HD  and am left with a 85GB bootcamp partition. I wanted to revert back to the original so I saved that 85GB with time machine on a external hard drive. I tried to erase the 85GB drive and then delete it from internet recovery and go back to my original 500GB. That didn't work and I was left with a blue screen saying enter to try again, f8 for something and another something but I can't remember what it was for. From there I reinstalled Mojave on the 85GB partition and went to disk utility on my MacBook. I tried to restore the 415GB partition and somehow screwed up and am left with 2 bootcamp partitions of 85GB and 415GB.

Here are pictures of the two in disk utility.

[image]

[image]

And here is a picture of when I type in diskutil list

[image]

And here is a picture of diskutil afps

[image]

Is there any way for me to get back to my original 500GB partition and restore back to the data that was on my 85GB partition.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You now have a broken disklayout with broken filesystems on it.  That is not a good thing at all.

I would suggest booting into rescue mode on the mac, erase the whole disk and (may not be necessary) set a single partition on it.  Then reinstall MacOS to that, restore your time machine backup, and then start a fresh time machine backup so you have that functional.  Then use boot camp again to reinstall a supported version of Windows next to MacOS.

Word of warning:  I tried using the native Windows tools to restore a Windows installation on my Mac a good while back.  It did not respect the partition layout but scratched the whole disk including my MacOS partition.  I only did that once.